# Ionic 1 AngularJS HTTP post vs. Ionic 3 Angular HTTP post

Tags: angular, cordova, http, ionic-framework, ionic3

I was worked much in the combination of Ionic 1 AngularJS, but after entered into the trend Ionic 3 Angular faced some issues in simple HTTP post request itself.

Let me explain the scenario please find below.

app.module.ts

```
import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpModule
  ]
})
```

login.ts

```
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

let link = 'http://demo.mydomain.com/myservice/login';

var headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

let postParams = JSON.stringify({"password":this.passCode, "userName":this.userName});

this.http.post(link, postParams, options)
.subscribe(data => {
    alert("data");
}, error => {
    alert("error");
});
```

While running out in the browser using ionic serve getting below response.

```
Failed to load http://demo.mydomain.com/myservice/login: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8105' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

As per my understanding if it's CORS based issues after installed the Chrome CORS plugin as well getting same issues.

Even I tried the direct running for the Android phone using `ionic cordova run android` that's too getting error block.

Comment: That update showed an error from code not actually included in the question, which isn't very helpful. If people want to see older versions they can look in the history; you should rewrite the question to be consistent with the updated version of code *and* its errors. Also note it's `withCredentials`, per [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#withCredentials).

Answer (score -1):

```
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

let link = 'http://demo.mydomain.com/myservice/login';

var headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
let postParams = JSON.stringify({"password":this.passCode, "userName":this.userName});

this.http.post(link, postParams, {headers: headers, WithCredentials:true})
.subscribe(data => {
    alert("data");
}, error => {
    alert("error");
});
```

In my ionic 3 application this much of code has worked for me in http post method.